# Receber valor do RadioButton no RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, radiobutton

boa noite.

Gostaria do auxilio de vocês em um problema que estou tendo, estou desenvolvendo um app pra um trabalho da faculdade, no caso eu vou ter uma activity que vai ter uma especie de pesquisa, ou quiz, como queiram chamar.

A pergunta, e as respostas estão armazenadas no firebase, eu listo tudo em um tela, onde o usuário poderá selecionar as opções para cada pergunta. Ai está minha dúvida, o que eu quero e o seguinte, o usuário devera selecionar todas as respostas, e no final clicar no botão, que irá redirecionar para uma outra activity que ira mostrar o resultado.

Esse é o problema, eu estou usando um recyclerview pra fazer a listagem das perguntas e respostas, todas em uma unica activity, como que eu faço para armazenar as respostas do usuario, para depois enviar o resultado para outra activity?

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fundo_degrade"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="br.com.cifrasemusica.cifrasmusica_teoriamusical.activity.ExercicioActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/Toolbar_Exercicio"
            layout="@layout/toolbar">
        </include>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/RecyclerView_Exercicio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_enviarExercicio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/fundo_botao"
        android:text="Confirmar"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity

```
public class ExercicioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Variaveis globais
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private String key;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private ArrayList<Questao> mContent;

    // Firebase
    private FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    private Query query;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercicio);

        // Recuperando os dados passados
        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extra != null) {
            this.key = extra.getString("key");
            this.name = extra.getString("name");
            this.description = extra.getString("description");

        }

        // Instanciando os objetos
        firestore = ConexaoFirebase.getFirestore();
        mContent = new ArrayList<>();

        // Configurando a toolbar
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.Toolbar_Exercicio);
        toolbar.setTitle(this.name);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Buscando conteudo no BD
        DocumentReference documentReference = firestore.collection("exercicios/").document(this.key);
        query = documentReference.collection("questoes/").orderBy("question");
        query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                mContent.clear();
                //Verificando se existem erros
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w("Error", "Erro ao ler as questões", e);
                    return;
                }

                // Lendo os dados e salvando no array
                for (DocumentSnapshot doc: documentSnapshots) {
                    if (doc != null) {
                        Questao questao = doc.toObject(Questao.class);
                        questao.setKey(doc.getId());
                        mContent.add(questao);
                    }
                }
                initRecyclerView();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView_Exercicio);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ExercicioAdapter adapter = new ExercicioAdapter(this, mContent);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

adapter

```
public class ExercicioAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExercicioAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

    // Variaveis globais
    private ArrayList<Questao> mContent = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public ExercicioAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Questao> mContent) {
        this.mContent = mContent;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_exercicios, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.question.setText(mContent.get(position).getQuestion());
        holder.op1.setText(mContent.get(position).getOp1());
        holder.op2.setText(mContent.get(position).getOp2());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mContent.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView question;
        RadioButton op1;
        RadioButton op2;
        Button botao_exercicio;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.question = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_titulo_exercicio);
            this.op1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RadioButton_op1_exercicio);
            this.op2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RadioButton_op2_exercicio);
            this.botao_exercicio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Button_enviarExercicio);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tive um problema semelhante, só que não encontrei nada a respeito. Então para resolver eu decidi fazer com que o usuário respondesse uma questão por vez, meio que ordenei as questões por números crescente no database, ai carregava a primeira questão, daí quando o usuário respondia ela jogava a resposta no db e adicionava +1 em uma "int" que criei para ser a  variável das questões e carregava a próxima questão (usando a mesma tela so fazendo outra consulta no db), ia fazendo isso até a variável das questões não existir no banco de dados.

É meio complicado entender, mas essa foi a base que usei, da pra começar a pensar a partir disso ai, boa sorte.